# Why would one ever advise another to hold a stock if they own it, but simultaneously advise against buying if one does not own it?

Tags: stocks

Logically, your decision about the future of a stock should not be influenced by your personal historical return from the stock. This is the notion behind the sunk cost fallacy. Therefore, if a stock is worth holding, to a newcomer it is worth buying. And if a stock is not worth buying to a newcomer, it should be sold by someone who already owns it. Yet I see this advice all the time.

Comment: Where do you see it?

Comment: @glibdud A [hold recommendation](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/h/hold.asp) means that "investors with existing long positions shouldn't sell but investors without a position shouldn't purchase either". There is also a saying often heard during downturns, "too late to sell, too early to buy".

Answer (score 3):

The only totally rational basis for this would be transaction costs -- if the stock is expected to appreciate slightly from here (so one should wait to sell), but not enough to cover commissions and spreads on a new purchase. Or similarly, if the stock is expected to dip slightly before heading higher (so one should wait to buy), but for an existing position it would not be worth the cost to sell and repurchase.

A psychological basis, however, is that if a stock has already gone up significantly since one bought it, there is a feeling of "playing with house money". The possibility of *giving back some of the gain* is not as painful as an outright loss. So one may be more willing to take the risk of continuing to hold because of the "cushion".